# Fedora 27 goes into emergency mode after boot

Tags: fedora, boot, acpi

When I list `journalctl -xb` I see the following errors:

```
ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/dswload2-191)
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170531/psobject-252)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP04.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
```

and

```
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT4._GTF AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
```

Any idea what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Comment: Fedora 27 is beyond end of life so there is little to no support and unless you can fix it yourself you are going to be out of luck. I suggest you boot an old kernel and upgrade to fedora 28 or  29 asap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is there any indication that there is a hardware problem involved?

Comment: Google search the error messages